# Possibility to disable the GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, jar, console

I made a Java program that you can run :
1 - Only with the GUI by launching the .jar .
2 - With the GUI and a console by launching a .bat .

```
java -jar "app.jar"
PAUSE
```

But now I would like to add the possibility to launch it ONLY with the console, that means without the GUI, I searched but didn't found how to do that.

Comment: This is where the MVC concept is really powerful and important. Basically you want to separate the functionality of whatever you're doing, from the "how" it gets done, meaning, you could either run it from the console or the GUI, but these are just wrappers which sit on top of the underlying functionality. The answer you're looking for is, you need to design it this way to start with, so you're probably in for some rework

Comment: You could use a command line switch. e.g. `java -jar "app.jar" -console` and then look at that switch in your main method. Or you could have two different classes in the jar and launch the console e.g. with `java -cp app.jar packagename.RunConsole`

Comment: I saw somewhere something like a "nogui" option ("-nogui" maybe I don't remember') and they guy didn't removed or changed his code, only inserted this ""nogui"" code in his .bat

Comment: Thanks SpiderPig but how can I get the "-console" in my code ? I mean check if it exists / is writed

Comment: Your main method looks like this: `public static void main(String[] args) {...}` args contains the command line arguments.

Comment: I tried with `if(args.equals("test"))` & `if(args.toString().contains("test"))` and `else{echo "no";}` but nothing happen, why ? :s

Comment: I updated my answer and added a hopefully helpful link (to a *basic* tutorial on such things). I hope you realized by now that *you* over-reacted; and are able to deal with my input by now.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question like: the application could work console-only, but it starts the ui always.

In that sense, look into you main method /class and simply check for the command line args. Maybe you simply add some -nogui parameter which you then use to put a condition around the launching of any gui components.

And given your comment: you have to compare your args like:

```
.... void main(String args[]) {
  for (String arg : args) {
    if (arg.equals(...
```

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) for more details regarding command line options.

Comment: I tried with `if(args.equals("test"))` & `if(args.toString().contains("test"))` and `else{echo "no";}` but nothing happen, why ?

Comment: See my updates. And seriously: if you don't understand how to access / compare those command line arguments, then you should really step back and do a lot more learning. That is super basic stuff.